# Someone deleted comments, so now new comments with exact same erroneous question appear again

Tags: discussion

In reply to [What is less doing with rpm, and how do I get that text without rpm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288105/what-is-less-doing-with-rpm-and-how-do-i-get-that-text-without-rpm)

OrangeDog has asked why not use the environment variable directly. I have answered in the comment, and modified the general answer to reflect his later comment. The comment discussion was deleted, so now someone new asks the exact same question that was already answered, in the comment section of the same answer.

The new comment by jpmc26 is a duplicate of OrangeDog's, and would have been avoided if the comments weren't deleted.
[What is less doing with rpm, and how do I get that text without rpm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288105/what-is-less-doing-with-rpm-and-how-do-i-get-that-text-without-rpm/288108#comment504009_288108)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments are generally intended to be temporary. Comments on questions should help understand what the problem is, and relevant details should be edited into the question until it has enough information to be answered. Comments on answers should address problems or ask follow-up questions, and the answer should be edited until it's correct/complete, especially if the follow-up question seems to be common. Once that's done the comments aren't needed anymore.

In this case, I would probably add a sentence to the answer like:

> You need to specify the script (`lesspipe.sh`) directly because `$LESSOPEN` begins with a `|`